# Endpoint is not hitting if there is a null property in the parameter object

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core

I am calling a .NET Core (.NET6) API into a blazor application. this is the point where I am calling API in blazor application

```
public class OrderManager : IOrderManager
{
   private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

   public OrderManager(HttpClient httpClient)
   {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
   }

    public async Task SaveOrder(Order order)
    {
        try
        {

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(.../api/Order/createGenericOrder, order);
            
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

---

then in my API, I have 2 custom middlewares. before coming to the endpoint both middleware execute first. then this is my API controller

```
[BLAuthorize]//custome authorize attribute
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
   ILogger<OrderController> _logger;
   public OrderController(ILogger<OrderController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        
    }

   [HttpPost("createGenericOrder")]
    public IActionResult CreateGenericOrder(Order order)
    {
        //
    }
}

public class Order
{
      public int OrderKey { get; set; } = 1;
      public CodeBaseResponse Location { get; set; } 
      public string OrderName{get;set;}

}

public class CodeBaseResponse 
{
    public int CodeKey { get; set; }
    public string CodeName { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing this **Order** type object parameter to this above controller action. Following you can see a JSON object  **Order** object that has been got in one API call.

```
 {
   "OrderKey":45897,

   "Location":{
                "CodeKey":14258,
                "CodeName":null,
            },
   "OrderName":null

}
```

now my problem is when we are going to pass the above type object my endpoint is not executing. the reason is this **Location.CodeName** and **OrderName** are being null.when I pass an empty string or some text with those they are working fine. I couldn't identify what is this issue. please help if there is anyone who knows a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice if you had posted the response you are getting, but for this particular case I think I know what you got:  You got an HTTP response code of **400 BAD REQUEST** stating `OrderName` or the other guy is a required field.

This happens because .Net6 comes with nullable reference types enabled.  If you open your project file (the one with the .csproj extension), you'll find this:  `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`.  Delete it if you want to opt out of nullable reference types.  It will now work as you expect.

Alternatively, if you do not want to opt out of nullable reference types, simply make your properties optional with a question mark, like this:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public int OrderKey { get; set; } = 1;
    public CodeBaseResponse Location { get; set; }
    public string? OrderName { get; set; }
}

public class CodeBaseResponse
{
    public int CodeKey { get; set; }
    public string? CodeName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes, I am getting a response as 400 BAD Request. 
And I tried your solution, but it is still not working, I can't set all properties with nullable types. because I am going to connect this app with several client apps which have been already created. then I have to change the object's properties of those clients as well.

Comment: Then just get rid of the nullable data types thing.  It works.  I tested both approaches.